# grav: Runtime Exception (400) after renaming files

Tags: php, templates, twig, content-management-system, grav

After creating a new theme using devtools:

- Renamed `user/pages/01.home/default.md` to `home.md`
- Copied `default.html.twig` in `user/themes/xyz/templates` to `home.html.twig`

Expected no change at all, cause I haven't changed the twig-file. I get an  error instead:

> Template home.html.twig is not defined.

But the file exists!? I'm using grav-admin 1.3.1, PHP 7.1.0 on Win10.

Comment: Nice! if you have any specific questions let us know. For now I'm flagging this as off-topic, as it's not clear what you are asking. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: @GrumpyCroutron: This IS a specific question. Have you understood the problem at all?

Comment: You should read my comment. Specifically "Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, **with research shown, and a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**"

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Asking for an example of renaming 2 files is ridiculous. You haven't read the question at all! I don't have to proof you, that I did reasearch either. Is this court or an Q&A site?

Comment: Good luck getting help if you aren't going to follow site guidelines.

Comment: Could you show us the frontmatter of the page and the structure of your folders ? (pages and templates)

Comment: The problem was described in details. This is a question with enough information to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Experience would suggest that it's one of three things.

1. A caching issue. Try clearing the site cache and trying again.
2. A naming issue. Did you copy `home.html.twig` to the same directory as the `default.html.twig` file? Double check that the names align properly, and you haven't accidentally inserted a space.
3. Who owns the new `home.html.twig` file? If `ls -l` lists the owner as anything other than the web user, you probably need to use `chown` to change the ownership to the web user.

Short of that, it would be difficult to offer better advice without seeing the code directly.

Comment: The problem should be caused by cache or permission or wrong folder. He/she already mentioned that he/she didn't modify the content of the files. Even if he/she did that and messed up something, we would get a different error.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem if cache is enabled. @user414873 you should clear the cache after renaming the files. If the site is in development, turn off cache unless you want to clear cache every time you make some changes.